# Grails can't find MySQL connector class

Tags: mysql, database, grails

In order to get MySQL working with a Grails app, I copied the JAR from the apt package (using Ubuntu Server 10.10, file is "/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar") to the Grails application's "lib" directory.

Then in the data source settings I changed the database URL to `url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/databasename?autoreconnect=true"`.

But now running the app gives me the error "ClassNotFoundException: org.mysql.jdbc.Driver". Similar problems on the mailing list didn't provide a solution to this. I've also tried to add the connector as dependency (+ Maven repos) but that didn't work either.

The JAR is obviously the correct file, so what can I do about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the driver name to:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: I'm feeling dumb right now, you were right. I even checked whether the JAR contained Driver.class but didn't see it was in the `com.*` package... Thanks!

Comment: Happens to all of us from time to time. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I run grails (version 2.0) alone, but when I run it with SpringSTS (or another IDE) there is no problem, so, I compared the project generated by grails (alone) and generated by spring sts.

The main difference between them was the .classpath file (located in projectroot/.classpath). To solve the problem  in the project generated without sts I've added the next line to .classpath file

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar"/>
```

I hope this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In DataSource.groovy:

```
dataSource {
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username = "xxx"
    password = "yyy"
}

...

environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/databasename?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&autoReconnect=true"
...
```